# How to get each returned result form function returning table?

Tags: postgresql

Here I have a function called 'returns_table' which returns multiple rows of records. In another method I am trying to access all records individually and concatenate them. But receiving error saying - 'multiple rows returned for a single variable. Here is my code:

```
for _i in (SELECT * from returns_table()) loop              
     _msg := _i;
end loop;
```

Is there any alternative to access each, individual row from function returning a table? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by concatenate records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `i` must be declared as a RECORD. See example:

```
DO $$
    DECLARE i       RECORD;
    DECLARE data1   INTEGER;
    DECLARE data2   INTEGER;
    DECLARE data3   INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)) AS t)
    LOOP
        data1   := i.column1;
        data2   := i.column2;
        data3   := i.column3;
        RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %', data1, data2, data3;
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Will give the following output:

```
NOTICE:  1, 2, 3
NOTICE:  4, 5, 6
NOTICE:  7, 8, 9

Query returned successfully with no result in 11 ms.
```